# Mutual information between $X$ and $f(X)$

Tags: random-variable, continuous-data, mutual-information

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables, where $Y=f(X)$ is a deterministic function of $X$. Furthermore suppose $X,Y$ are continuous and that $f$ is smooth.

Is the mutual information between $X$ and $Y$ well defined in this case? I have the intuition that it can only be zero (if $f$ is a constant function) or infinity.

Comment: The usual definitions of MI apply only to discrete variables or jointly continuous variables or, more generally, measures for which one is absolutely continuous with respect to the other.  This case is none of the above.  What definition do you have in mind, then?

Comment: It shouldn't be infinite because for example $I(X,X) = H(X)$.

Comment: @whuber Say we take a limit, $Y = f(X) + \epsilon z$ where $z$ is a standard normal and $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. In that case the mutual information tends to infinity, correct?

Comment: @Simone That is not correct for continuous distributions.

Comment: @whuber Well by taking this limit I just answered my own question. Indeed the mutual information goes to infinity.

Comment: Why should mutual information be a continuous function in this limit??

Comment: @whuber Why not? I can always say I *define* it as this limit. Unless there is another mainstream definition which applies here, I don't see any inconsistencies. Do you?

Comment: According to the usual definitions, the MI is *undefined.*  In order to define it as a limit (which indeed is a reasonable thing to attempt), you have to show that the value does not depend on how you take the limit.

Comment: @whuber For now I am contempt with the limit I took here, because I have a physical problem in mind (which brought me to this question) where this limit makes much sense. However if someone can come up with different ways of taking the limit (hopefully not too pathological) that lead to a different result I'd be interested in seeing that. I can't think of any.

Comment: I think your intuition is correct because under independence and non-constancy of a smooth $f,$ the joint distribution has a continuous component (in its Lebesgue decomposition as a measure) and that will be infinitely distant from the singular distribution of $(X,f(X)).$

Comment: Great, that's another way of thinking about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose that $Y=f(X)+\epsilon Z$ where $Z$ is a standard normal, and we take the limit $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$

The mutual information equals $$I = H(Y) - H(Y|X),$$ where $H(Y)$ is the entropy of $Y$ and $H(Y|X)$ is the conditional entropy of $Y$ on $X$. Since $Z$ is normal, $H(Y|X)=\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi e\epsilon^2)$.

If $f$ is not constant and smooth, then $H(Y)$ stays positive and finite. But as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ we find $H(Y|X)\rightarrow-\infty$ and therefore $I=\infty$ in this limit.

If $f(X)=c$ is a constant, then $H(Y)=H(Y|X)$ for any positive $\epsilon$, and therefore in this case the limit is $I=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Although $f$ is stated as neural network, I think theorem 1 of paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.09766.pdf will answer part of your question, i.e. , if $f$ is bi-Lipschitz then $I(Y, X) = \infty$.

Furthermore, $f(X) = c$ is not a bi-Lipschitz function. A example of piecewise linear function， a general form of constant function， is present in section 4.3； I think at least for that example the mutual information is a finite constant for piecewise linear function.